# Linux GPIO driver probe fails

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

I am trying to write a small kernel module that can control some LEDs connected to the GPIO pins on my RaspberryPi 4 Model B. My Pi is running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)` and Linux kernel v6.1.21-v7l+.

I am currently trying to figure out how the DeviceTree works with my kernel module.

This is my DTS file

```dts
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            led {
                compatible = "led";
                status = "okay";
                label = "led";
                led-gpio = <&gpio 17 0>,
                           <&gpio 27 0>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

My kernel module code is

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/mod_devicetable.h>
#include <linux/property.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/of_device.h>
#include <linux/gpio/consumer.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("****");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");

static int dt_probe(struct platform_device *pdev);
static int dt_remove(struct platform_device *pdev);

static struct of_device_id led_ids[] = {
    {
        .compatible = "led",
    }, { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, led_ids);

static struct platform_driver led_driver = {
    .probe = dt_probe,
    .remove = dt_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = "led",
        .of_match_table = led_ids,
    },
};

static struct gpio_desc *blue = NULL, *red = NULL;

static struct proc_dir_entry *proc_file = NULL;

static ssize_t led_write(struct file *filp, const char *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offset) {
    int value;
    char command[2];

    if (copy_from_user(command, user_buffer, 1)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to read command from user\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    command[1] = 0; // null terminate the string so that kstrtoint doesn't fail

    if (kstrtoint(command, 10, &value)) {
        pr_err("[led] Invalid command from user\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    gpiod_set_value(blue, !!value);
    return count;
}

static ssize_t led_read(struct file *filp, char __user *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offset) {
    int value;
    char led_value_str;

    if (*offset)
        return 0;

    value = gpiod_get_raw_value(blue);

    switch (value) {
        case 0:
            led_value_str = '0';
            break;
        case 1:
            led_value_str = '1';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (copy_to_user(user_buffer, &led_value_str, 1)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to copy led value to user\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    (*offset)++;
    return 1;
};

static struct proc_ops fops = {
    .proc_write = led_write,
    .proc_read = led_read,
};

static int dt_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) {
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    const char *label;
    int ret;

    /* Check for device properties */
    if (!device_property_present(dev, "label")) {
        pr_err("[led] Device property 'label' not found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Read device properties */
    ret = device_property_read_string(dev, "label", &label);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to read 'label'\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Init GPIO */
    blue = gpiod_get_index(dev, "led", 0, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
    if (IS_ERR(blue)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to setup blue LED\n");
        return PTR_ERR(blue);
    }

    red = gpiod_get_index(dev, "led", 1, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
    if (IS_ERR(red)) {
        printk("[led] Failed to setup red LED\n");
        gpiod_put(blue);
        return PTR_ERR(red);
    }

    /* Creating procfs file */
    proc_file = proc_create("led", 0666, NULL, &fops);
    if (proc_file == NULL) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to create /proc/led\n");
        gpiod_put(blue);
        gpiod_put(red);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    pr_info("[led] Successfully setup GPIO driver\n");
    return 0;
}

static int dt_remove(struct platform_device *pdev) {
    pr_info("[led] Removing device from tree\n");
    gpiod_put(blue);
    proc_remove(proc_file);
    return 0;
}

static int __init led_init(void) {
    pr_info("[led] Loading LED driver\n");
    if (platform_driver_register(&led_driver)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to register driver\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
};

static void __exit led_cleanup(void) {
    pr_info("[led] Cleaning up LED driver\n");
    platform_driver_unregister(&led_driver);
};

module_init(led_init);
module_exit(led_cleanup);
```

My Makefile

```make
obj-m += led.o

KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all: module dt
    echo Built Device Tree Overlay and kernel module

module:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
dt: ledoverlay.dts
    dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o ledoverlay.dtbo ledoverlay.dts
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
    rm -rf ledoverlay.dtbo
```

Loading the DTBO object works fine, but when I try to load my module the following gets printed to `dmsg` -

```
[ 9573.984173] [led] Loading LED driver
[ 9573.984509] [led] Failed to setup blue LED
[ 9573.984518] led: probe of led failed with error -2
```

Sources I looked at -

1. https://github.com/Johannes4Linux/Linux_Driver_Tutorial/blob/main/21_dt_gpio/dt_gpio.c
2. https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Linux-Device-Driver-Development-Second-Edition/blob/main/Chapter16/gpio/gpio-descriptor-module.c

Does anyone have any insight on why the call to `gpiod_get_index()` fails? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something or doing something wrong.

Edit:

If I change the DTS file and split the GPIOs this

```dts
...
    led {
        compatible = "led";
                status = "okay";
                label = "led";
                led-blue-gpio = <&gpio 17 0>,;
                led-red-gpio = <&gpio 27 0>;
    };
```

And the module code to use `gpiod_get()` instead of `gpiod_get_index()` like so

```c
...
    blue = gpiod_get(dev, "led-blue", GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
...
    red = gpiod_get(dev, "led-red", GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
```

Everything seems to work fine.

Comment: There is already a module called `leds-gpio`, just enable it in your kernel and properly write DTS, no C programming is needed.

Comment: `return -1 * IS_ERR(x);` is wrong. Replace it with `return PTR_ERR(x);` to return a proper error code.

Comment: Returning the proper error code would be especially useful for you if the error happened to be `-EPROBE_DEFER`.

Comment: @0andriy yeah I saw that. This is just a small project for me to get to know the internals of the kernel better, so I do want to write some C code. Do you maybe have an idea as to what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: @IanAbbott what would I do in that case?

Comment: @CoolSteve If your probe function returns `-EPROBE_DEFER` it will be called again automatically when some other device has been successfully probed. This could happen if your probe function is executed before the GPIO controller has been probed, for example.

Comment: @IanAbbott I made changes as per you advice and updated the question

Comment: Are you sure that `gpio` is a valid phandle in the device tree?

Comment: @0andriy I'm pretty sure. I updated the code in the question to show how I managed to get it to work, though I would still like to understand what was wrong with my first approach

Comment: Okay, so either the problem is with the naming of GPIO property, or in its value. I don’t see the code issue.`-2` IIRC is `ENOENT` meaning that software can not find the description.

Comment: Rename the `led-gpio` property to `led-gpios`.

Comment: I'd also recommend using less generic "compatible" strings. Include a "vendor," tag to avoid matching other device tree nodes by mistake.

Comment: @IanAbbott Renaming `led-gpis` to `led-gpios` worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, as [@IanAbbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) mentioned, the issue was with the name of the `led-gpio` property. I renamed it to `led-gpios` and it worked with `gpiod_get_index()`.